# Getting "#1111 - Invalid use of group function" without using GROUP in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, doctrine, doctrine-orm

```
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('t');

    return $qb
        ->join('t.customers', 'c')
        ->where($qb->expr()->eq('t.user', $user->getId()))
        ->andWhere($qb->expr()->gt($qb->expr()->count('c'), 0))
        ->orderBy('t.name')->getQuery()->getResult();
```

The above query (Doctrine2 generated one) is giving me this error:

> `#1111 - Invalid use of group function`

but the strange thing is i'm not using `GROUP BY`. Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

```
SELECT t0_.id AS id0,
       t0_.slug AS slug1,
       t0_.name AS name2,
       t0_.description AS description3,
       t0_.user_id AS user_id4
FROM tag t0_ 
    INNER JOIN customers_tags c2_ ON t0_.id = c2_.tag_id
        INNER JOIN customer c1_ ON c1_.id = c2_.customer_id
WHERE t0_.user_id = 1 AND COUNT(c1_.id) > 0
ORDER BY t0_.name ASC
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using an aggregate function `count()` in the where clause which is not allowed.

Conditions on aggregate functions need to go into a HAVING clause

```
....
WHERE t0_.user_id = 1
HAVING count(c1_.id) > 0
```

And of course you'll need to use a GROUP BY to get correct results (although MySQL will probably let you get away with not using a GROUP BY - but then the results are unpredictable)

Answer (score 3):

There is no need in joins and havings. Simply use `SIZE` function:

```
$qb->where('SIZE(t.customers) = 0');
```

This will give you all rows without attached customers

Comment: Sir, you made my day. Struggling since 24h on a way to do a double check on an array collection (specified item in the array collection OR the size of the array collection is 0) This perfectly did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

"Count" can not be used in where without group by, count is "group function"